# How to automate data gathering and not freeze in 10%

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, loops, for-loop

**What I have:**

*(take a look or fire on localhost if required: http://pastebin.com/virLR7dF)*

*(take a look on image presenting my case: http://iv.pl/images/47143498348127804676.png)*

I have a PHP script that crawles given websites, and extracts data as varibles:

```
$ID = "data"; //this is just an example
$name = "data";
$price = "data";
$image = "data";
```

Script will put this data in a MySQL DB.

**What is wrong?**

I can automate it with a for loop so I will get more data at once. But if I loop it 1,000,000 times my script will freeze at some point, and starting over *(finding where it broke and starting from that point)* is problematic.

**How with PHP/JS make it to:**

**1.** gather 10 portions of data

**2.** stop and display information about gathered data

**3.** gather next 10 portions of data

**4.** stop and add new information to previosly displayed information

***** have a PAUSE function to stop after next portion gathered

***** have a RESUME funcion to start after last portion gathered

Comment: What do you need JavaScript for? Or is Node.js an alternative to PHP?

Comment: What is the problem- you said it freezes but your question is how to write several parts of code? If you want somebody to write code for you go to freelancer dot com or something. Ask a specific question on a specific problem please

Comment: Thank for your reply ppumkin. I have whole script, just dont know tools how to make PHP stop for a while and ADD pulled data to EXISTING and already DISPLAYED list of gathered data. Arun already helped with sleep().

Comment: @Bergi - I dont know, thats why Im asking

Comment: Do you want just a PHP script or is it a Web application that should stream the results to the client?

Comment: @Bergi - yes, just presenting data.

Comment: Graphical representation of my case: http://iv.pl/images/47143498348127804676.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output Buffering might be helping you in PHP

Try [ob_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) & [ob_flush](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

> **ob_start** This function will turn output buffering on. While output
>   buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than
>   headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.
>
> **ob_flush** This function will send the contents of the output buffer (if
>   any)

Answer (score 0):

There's some things that may cause problems when doing this.

1) An error gets triggered inside the loop and the script stops executing.

Solution: turn errors into exceptions which is catchable

2) You exceed the time limit.

Solution: Set the time limit to zero

Example:

```
set_error_handler(function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if($errno != E_STRICT && $errno != E_DEPRECATED && $errno != E_NOTICE) {
      throw new Exception($errstr.' in '.$errfile.' on line '.$errline);
    }
    return false;
});

set_time_limit(0);

function my_loop_func() {
 // do what ever...
}

while(true) {
  try {
     my_loop_func();
  }
  catch(Exception $e) {
    // write some log message here might be good
  }
  sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that example, I will look on it afternoon.